# Use of captured image bitmap outside onActivityResult method

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I am taking photo from my activity using camera intent as shown in the below code, but i need to use the captured image bitmap outside the onActivityResult() method but this is not working, i tried to declare the bitmap outside the method and then use outside the method but this did not work, it seems that the bitmap did not catch the image in the onActivityResult, so can anyone help in order to use the bitmap of captured image outside the method or to save it and get its path like using the select image from gallery, so my goal is to use the bitmap of captured image for image processing purpose outside the onActivityResult() method, below is my code, thanks

```
 captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
                } else {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        });
```

and this the onActivityResult() method:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        imageSelected.setImageBitmap(photo);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this steps and it worked for me

1)  define a Bitmap Object above of your `onCreate` method like bellow

```
Bitmap photo;
```

2) instead of `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` in `onActivityResult` write bellow code

```
photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

and after that you can access to your photo object everywhere in your activity you like

Comment: This do not work because Bitmap photo should be declared outside the onCreate() method in the beginning of the class otherwise we cannot use it in any method of the activity

Comment: it works finally, your answer gave me an idea and helped me thank you, the solution is to declare Bitmap photo at the beginning of the class outside and the oncreate method initialize it it by ( photo =null;) and then use  photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); in the onActivityResult and then you can use it everywhere in the activity, i tried this before but without initializing in the onCreate() and did not work so the key is initializing it in onCreate(); Thanks you!!

Comment: I said a bitmap above of onCreate method i mean a bitmap at the beginning of the class outside of the onCreate not in the onCreate

Comment: @wisam He is right, Please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @hadimohammadi yes I tried it before and did not work without initializing it in the onCreate() as " photo =null" so it must be declared above the onCreate() and initialized inside the oncreat() by null, thanks